# jqgrid filterToolbar search input size

Tags: jqgrid

I'm starting to use filtertoolbar: `myGrid.jqGrid('filterToolbar', {stringResult: true, searchOnEnter: false, defaultSearch : "cn"});`

My question Is If I can control the search inputs size -

**UPDATE**: It's height and width size .

Thank's In Advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I understand you correct you should include in `colModel` in the definition of the column which input size you want to restrict the option like

```
searchoptions:{ attr: {maxlength: 5}}
```

In the example in the corresponding input field of the searching toolbar will be allowed to type not more as five characters.

**UPDATED**: I don't understand why you need such behavior, but you can use `dataInit` of the `searchoptions` to set height and width of the input control. To do this you can use either jQuery.css or jQuery.height and jQuery.width methods:

```
searchoptions:{
    attr: {maxlength: 5},
    dataInit: function(elem) {
        //$(elem).css({height:"30px", width:"40px"});
        $(elem).height(30).width(40);
    }
}
```

If you increase the height of the control in the searching toolbar you should change additionally

```
var myGrid = $("#list");
// ...
var $search_toolbar = $("tr.ui-search-toolbar", myGrid[0].grid.hDiv);
$search_toolbar.height(30);
```

You should do this of course after the call of `filterToolbar` which create the searching toolbar.

See small demo [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SimpleLocalGridWithSearchingToolbarCustom.htm).

Comment: thank's.. sorry, but when I wrote size , I ment to it's width and height size.. I updated my question.

Comment: Awesome job Oleg!! I was looking for this as well. Great answers as always.

Comment: Oleg: Can you please view [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11216815/get-a-grids-filter-parameters)? I'm really stuck! Thanks.