# Get a Grid's Filter Parameters

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I'm using jQGrid and I'm wondering if there is a way to get the current filters that have been applied to the grid I'm viewing. For example, if the grid has been sorted by a certain column (asc or desc), search parameters that may have been applied, etc.

Here is my problem: I would like to pass some parameters back to the previous grid I was viewing (or the last page) so that I can see the previous grid as it was when I navigated forward. Basically, I have a link the user will click which navigates back to the page with the previous grid they were viewing. I want to pass the filter parameters along with that link.

**Overall Example:**

1. I filtered the Client grid by the `client_name` field in `asc` order.
2. I then clicked a link which takes me to a separate page with a new grid.
3. I want to navigate back to the Client grid I was previously on, seeing my grid with `client_name` filtered in `asc` order as it was when I had navigated away the first time.

Currently, I am able to navigate back to the Clients grid but I would like to get the filter parameters that had been applied so I can pass them with my link back.

Let me know if I'm being specific enough!

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend to read [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8436273/315935) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8547852/315935). The answers shows how to solve very close problem by the usage of `window.localStorage`. The most important options of jqGrid which defines the state are: `sortname`, `sortorder` for sorting, `search` and `postData` (mostly `postData.filters`) for filtering, `page` for paging. Moreover if you use [columnChooser](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:jquery_ui_methods#column_chooser) you would need to use `remapColumns` option of jqGrid. You can include additionally take in consideration the information about current selected row/rows (`selrow` or `selarrrow`). So the exact list of the parameters which you need save or restore depends on your requirements.

Comment: I'll check those links out later on today when I get the time!

Comment: Oleg: I'm thinking I would like to shy away from `localStorage` since I have clients using my application who use IE7. Instead, I would like to save the jqGrid state in a MySQL DB. Is there any short way to grab the current states of: `sortname`, `sortorder`, `search`, `postData`, `postData.filters`, `page`, and `remapColumns`? Maybe something like `jqGrid('getGridParam', 'sortname')`? Thanks as always Oleg!

Comment: @FastTrack: You can just follow the example from [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8436273/315935). It uses `getGridParam` to  get parameters `sortname`, `sortorder`, `search`, `postData`, etc. You can send the current grid state to the server by `$.ajax` instead of call of `window.localStorage.setItem`.

Comment: Oleg: Ok, great! And I'm assuming I would set the parameters with `setGridParam`? Also, does that example cover the columns order and if each column is hidden or not? I couldn't find it from just reading over the example. Thanks!

Comment: Also, when I use `jqGrid('getGridParam', 'postData.filters')` to get the search parameters the user has used, it keeps returning `null`. I'm assuming I'm doing something wrong there :-)

Comment: @FastTrack: There are no parameter `'postData.filters'`. If you need to get `filters` property of the parameter `postData` you should use `.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'postData').filters`

Comment: Ok, I'm getting the filters correctly with `.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'postData').filters` but do I set them the same way but with `setGridParam`? Sorry for so many questions!

Comment: @FastTrack: You can get **the reference** to internal object `postData` by `.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'postData')` and then set any its property like `filters` directly. No additional call of `setGridParam` is required because you will work with *reference* to `postData` used by jqGrid.

Comment: Ok, so basically if I want to set the filters equal to a variable it would look like this: `.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'postData').filters = myFilters`?

Comment: @FastTrack; Yes, it's correct. You should don't forget to use `JSON.stringify` with `myFilters` objest. So the value of `filters` property must be JSON *string*.