# jqgrid filterToolbar search input align center

Tags: jqgrid

I added a filterToolbar search box to my grid and changed it's height style like 
in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5967028/jqgrid-filtertoolbar-search-input-size) question.

I want to position this input to be in the center, 
(I tried `text-align:center`, but it didn't work).
How is it possible to center the input box inside the column header?

**UPDATE:**
This is my colModel code:

```
{width:10,name:'Code1',index:'Code1', jsonmap:'Code1',searchoptions:{dataInit: function(elem){$(elem).css('font','15px'); $(elem).height(18);}}},
{width:40,name:'DescriptionHe1',index:'DescriptionHe1', jsonmap:'DescriptionHe1',searchoptions:{dataInit: function(elem){$(elem).css('font','15px');$(elem).height(18);}}, hidden:(language == "he")?false:true},
{width:40,name:'DescriptionEn1',index:'DescriptionEn1', jsonmap:'DescriptionEn1',searchoptions:{dataInit: function(elem){$(elem).css('font','15px');$(elem).height(18);}}, hidden:(language == "en")?false:true},                                                    
{width:10,name:'Code2',index:'Code2', jsonmap:'Code2',searchoptions:{dataInit: function(elem){$(elem).css('font','15px'); $(elem).height(18);}}},
{width:40,name:'DescriptionHe2',index:'DescriptionHe2', jsonmap:'DescriptionHe2',searchoptions:{dataInit: function(elem){$(elem).css('font','15px');$(elem).height(18);}}, hidden:(language == "he")?false:true},
{width:40,name:'DescriptionEn2',index:'DescriptionEn2', jsonmap:'DescriptionEn2',searchoptions:{dataInit: function(elem){$(elem).css('font','15px');$(elem).height(18);}}, hidden:(language == "en")?false:true}
```

Thank's In Advance.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose that additional CSS which you use changes default behavior of jqGrid. **jqGrid *center* all input fields from the searching toolbar per default**.

To change the style of elements from the searching bar you can use `attr` of the [searchoptions](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:search_config#colmodel_options).

[The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/CenterInputInSearchingBar.htm) display the following:

[image]

The demo uses

```js
cmTemplate: {
    searchoptions: {
        attr: {
            style: "width:auto;padding:0;max-width:100%"
        }
    }
}
```

to set common style for all elements of the searching bar. Additionally I set `maxlength` and `size` attributes for different columns. For example

```js
searchoptions: { attr: { maxlength: 6, size: 6 }}
```

[Another demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/CenterInputInSearchingBar1.htm) shows how to set different alignment for different elements of the searching toolbar:

[image]

In the demo I used for left alignment fields the property

```js
searchoptions: {
    attr: {
        maxlength: 6,
        size: 6,
        style: "width:auto;padding:0;max-width:100%;float:left"
    }
}
```

and

```js
searchoptions: {
    attr: {
        maxlength: 6,
        size: 6,
        style: "width:auto;padding:0;max-width:100%;float:right"
    }
}
```

for right alignment fields.

To set the height of the input field I used `height` inside of `searchoptions.attr.style`:

```js
style: "width:auto;padding:0;max-width:100%;height:5em;float:left"
```

P.S. I used additionally CSS

```css
.ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-htable .ui-search-toolbar th {
    height: auto; padding-bottom: 1px
}
```

to improve a little visibility of the searching toolbar.

Comment: Thank's for the detailed answer! I tried changing my code to whta you did, but It dosen't work good, I still can't see the input in the center. I want the search input to be with height, and to be 100% width with a little space in the sides. Is this possible? (I've updated the question with my code). thank's!